# Rename class fields accessors in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, class, field, rename

Say I have

```
public class Person {

int id;
String regDate;
String name;
String surname;

// constructors, setters and getters and toString
```

If I rename id I want to rename it all across the class setters etc.
Currently I use ctr+f find replace, but that renames also my import statements and comments. :-)

And also if I change type, lets say int to String for id I want type to be changed also all over the class(getters,setters,toString).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the *Outline view* -> make sure that fields are visible ("Hide fields" icon at top cannot be pressed) -> select the field you want to rename -> Alt + Shift + R -> give a new name for fields / accessor -> check "Rename getter..." and "Rename setter" -> click "Ok".

Regarding the second part of your question, this type of refactoring is probably currently unavailable because someone suggested it too on Eclipse Community Forums this year in [this thread](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/655722/).